# Tensorflow use particular gpus

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I have seen the question multiple times but never got a straight forward answer. In one node of our cluster we have 7 gpus. I want to use two specific gpus in `tensorflow2`, say `GPU 3` and `GPU 5`. How do I select these two GPUs?
I have tried:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.set_visible_devices([physical_devices[3],physical_devices[5]],'GPU')
```

Still it is using `GPU 0` and I am getting error because someone else is already using it.

If parallel use could be an issue, please suggest me how to use a specific one, say GPU 3? And how will I check that only GPU 3 is being used?

Comment: Have you tried the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` method? `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` seems to be implemented by NVidia, whereas Tensorflow is from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Gpus meet the Hardware requirements for parallel usage? and have you checked that CUDA and CuDNN drivers are detected by your system?

Comment: Yes, of course.